# ¿ Como eliminar los n últimos caracteres de una cadena en Java ? Java

Tags: java, string

Qué formas de Eliminar una cierta cantidad de caracteres de Una cadena , por ejemplo `cadena = "123456789"` , quisiera eliminar 2 últimos caracteres de la cadena. la salida sería `"1234567"`.

**¿Qué formas existen para realizar esto?** que funcione para cualquier cantidad de caracteres a eliminar (*últimos*)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tomando como ejemplo la cadena `"123456789"`, y una variable con la cantidad de caracteres a Eliminar

```
     String  cadena= "123456789";
     int cantidad= 2; /* Total de elementos a Eliminar*/  
      /* Total de elementos a Mostrar*/      
     int m = Math.max(0, cadena.length() - cantidad);
```

- Haciendo uso del método [Substring(int inicio, int final)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) , similar a  [SubSequence(int inicio, int final)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence(int,%20int))

  ```
  System.out.println(cadena.substring(0, cadena.length()-cantidad));
  System.out.println(cadena.subSequence(0, m).toString());
  ```
- Haciendo uso de la clase [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para asignar el tamaño de la cadena de salida en este caso el valor obtenido anteriormente `m`

  ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cadena);
   sb.setLength(m);
   System.out.println(sb.toString());
  ```
- Convirtiendo la cadena en Un `Array` de Caracteres mediante el método [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) para luego pasar dicho `Array` al Constructor del `String`
  [new String(char[] chars,int a ,int b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[],%20int,%20int))

  ```
   char[] cs = cadena.toCharArray();
   System.out.println(new String(cs, 0, m));
  ```
- Expresión Regular (modificar el 2 por el número de caracteres a Eliminar)

  ```
   System.out.println(string.replaceFirst("[\\s\\S]{0,2}$", ""));
  ```

> El tipo de dato String no puede ser modificado después de ser creado.(Inmutable)

Comment: Muy completo, gracias!

Answer (score 7):

Puedes eliminar asi:

```
String cadena = "123456789";
cadena = cadena.substring(0, cadena.length() - 2);
```

ya esta eliminado solo tienes que jugar o variar la cantidad de caracteres que quieres eliminar.

Valga la pena aclarar que los String en java son **inmutables**.

Comment: Ha funcionado a la primera! Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacer uso del método `[substring(int)][1]` y `[length()][1]`,

```
public String cortarCadena(int cantQuitar, String cadena)
{
   return cadena.substring(length()-cantQuitar);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

La *forma* más simple es usando el método `substring` de la clase `java.lang.String`. Por otra parte, si planeas reutilizar este fragmento de código con otras cadenas y longitudes, te recomiendo colocarlo en un método. Es decir (por ejemplo):

❐ ***Código***

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("\"%s\"%n", acortar("123456789", 2));
        System.out.printf("\"%s\"%n", acortar("123456789", 4));
        System.out.printf("\"%s\"%n", acortar("123456789", 8));
        System.out.printf("\"%s\"%n", acortar("123456789", 10));
    }

    public static String acortar(String cadena, int n) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(cadena, "La cadena no puede ser nula.");
        int indice = n > cadena.length() ? 0 : cadena.length() - n;
        return cadena.substring(0, indice);
    }

}
```

❐ ***Salida***

```
"1234567"
"12345"
"1"
""
```